# Is it possible to flash htc desire on linux (drivers concern)?

Tags: htc-desire, rom-flashing, linux

I'd like to flash 'HTC desire' and found this:

http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/Cyanogenmod-on-my-HTC-Desire-the-easy-way.aspx

I started to wonder if I'm able to do the flash.. because i use Debian and the tutorial is definitely for windows user.

I'm worried about these points:

> - EDIT: As Dan pointed out in the comments: Make sure you have HTC Sync
>     on your system or get the drivers from the link he posted in the
>     comments!
> - installed the windows hboot usb driver: http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/windows_hboot_driver_install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to flash android devices under linux. The fact is that Android does not need drivers - both adb and fastboot use libusb and talk to the devices directly. Your main concern should be finding compatible fastboot binary - some OEMs use proprietary fastboot extensions to handle certain functions.

Obviously you can not expect to be able to follow the windows tutorial under linux. Fortunately for you unrevoked (the tool used in the tutorial you linked) has a [linux version](http://downloads.unrevoked.com/recovery/3.32/reflash.tar.gz) as well.

Comment: Thanks, so shall I begin executing steps from the tutorial since Linux has necessary drivers or i need something else? Can You expand the thought about fastboot? I see nothing about the fastboot in the tutorial.

Comment: You do often need to setup permissions for ADB to work on Linux (or kill the ADB server and rerun as root), similar to here the format is different for different versions: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html . I don't know about fastboot offhand. Although automated tools like that unrevoked thing looks often use both fastboot and adb as well even adb is just used to send the phone reboot commands.